# Discord.js: how to use module.exports

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i am currently trying to create a discord-bot with discord.js using the official documentation / instructions (https://discordjs.guide/). At the point "Command handling" I have to export the different commands into own files and then export them, so that I can use them in the main-file. I have already done some research and looked at how exporting in node.js works. For example

```
function add (a, b) {
return a + b;
}

function subtract (a, b) {
return a - b;
}

module.exports = {
    add: add,
    subtract: subtract
}
```

However, I don't understand why this function exports like this:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Ping!',
    execute(message, args) {
            message.channel.send('Pong.');
    },
};
```

I didn't find anything on the internet about the "execute" function and I don't understand why I can't just export it like this:

```
function ping(message, args) {
    message.channel.send('Pong!');
}
module.exports = {
    ping: ping,
};
```

or like this:

```
exports.ping = function (message, args) {
    message.channel.send('Pong!');
};
```

Would be nice if someone could explain this to me, especially the "execute" function :)

Comment: The execute function is a method inside of the exported object. It is called once you have added the commands to `client.commands` like this: `client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);`

Comment: Okay, but can I export the functions like I did in my examples?

Comment: So without the "execute" function

Comment: I don't see why not

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti So you could also say that "execute" is similar to "name" and "description". With "name" I specify the name of the function, etc. and with "execute" I specify what should be executed when called?

Comment: Yeah, so `name` and `description` are properties, but `execute` is a method which is why you can call `execute(message, args);`

Comment: You can code your bot however you want. This is just the standard convention  that discordjs has adopted along with others who write bots, so sticking to the convention allows you can use a consistent pattern to call different commands, and you can also follow other code and projects that use the same pattern and vice versa.